# Property[nama_anak1] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got this error : Property[nama_anak1] does not exist on this collection instance when I was trying to catch the data. If I dd($data->keluarga) it shows the data.

Below is the code I have on controller and view

[In My Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNvXP.jpg)

[In My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAICi.jpg)

What should I do?

Comment: `keluarga` must be a collection. you need to loop through the collection to access properties of individual instances of `keluarga`

Comment: keluarga actually a relationship which is defined in Model..

Comment: please post the code snippets on the question rather than in images, as mentioned above you need to loop through keluarga. So do foreach($data->keluarga as $keluarga) { ...

Answer (score 0):

in your controller change it to this

```
$data['keluarga'] = PernikahanModel::with('keluarga')->find($id)->get();

return view('pernikahan.detail')->with($data);
```

then in your blade, you could just use

```
{{ $keluarga->nama_anak1 }}
```